# Execute a stored procedure from within another stored procedure's SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to execute a stored procedure X from within the SELECT statement of stored procedure Y, so that X's value can be returned as part of Y's data.

I am trying the following syntax, but it's apparently not valid.

```
SELECT name, type, (EXEC X @type=type)
FROM table
```

As I hope you can see above, I need to pass the current row's type value to procedure X to get the proper return value.

Disclaimer: I probably just don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: You can't use a stored procedure to get the value for a single column. Perhaps using a stored procedure is the wrong approach? For something like an inline table valued function would be more appropriate.

Comment: I still cant see why you cant use stored procedure.

Comment: @Denn because a stored procedure returns an integer. Any result set is not actually being returned from the stored procedure. And there is no guarantee that it will return only a single result set. And there is nothing preventing multiple columns in a given result set. It just doesn't logically make sense to use a procedure like this.

Comment: @sean: Agreed but the way he wrote the query I assumed type returns only 1 result. Though I must agree on your point too.

Comment: @Denn but your assessment is a logical one (and likely correct). But how would you write a query engine that would do that? And again, the result set is NOT being returned from the procedure. The return from a stored procedure is an integer. The output resultset(s) are extra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach what you have tried is invalid. Instead of the `X` as the stored procedure convert it as [user-defined function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms191320.aspx). like the below

```
Create function dbo.fnGetTypeDetail
(
 @type varchar(50)
)
returns varchar(100)
As
Begin 
   return --do your operation;
End
```

And replace your query as:

```
SELECT name, type, dbo.fnGetTypeDetail(type) AS TypeDetail
FROM table
```

For sample, I created a scalar function. Based on your requirement you can create inline table valued function as per the [example](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/KY3T010412-Different-Types-of-SQL-Server-Functions.html)

Comment: I would agree this will work but scalar functions are horribly inefficient. And when used as a column value they are just awful.

Comment: While waiting for responses, I went ahead and was able to create a function (per Sean Lange's original post), and have been able to obtain the values I needed.  Thank you, all, for your input.  Saved the day!

Answer (score 1):

You can't EXEC a stored proc inside a SELECT statement.

What you can do is INSERT..EXEC a stored proc into a temp table, and then run a SELECT statement that queries that temp table, while joining to other tables if desired.

Psuedo-example:

```
INSERT INTO #Tmp (Column1) EXEC X;

SELECT Name, Type, (SELECT Column1 FROM #tmp)
FROM MyTable
```